# ImportError: cannot import name 'Template' from 'jinja2'

Tags: python, jinja2, visualization, folium

i get this error when i import *folium *

```
aws-sam-cli==1.95.0
Flask==2.2.5
folium==0.11.0
Jinja2==3.0.3
```

**error**
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Template' from 'jinja2'`

What can I do to solve this issue?

I tried

- To create a new virtual environment and install only the necessary libraries for your project
- pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
- pip uninstall jinja2
- pip install --upgrade Jinja2

Comment: Did you create a file in your project named `jinja2.py`? Please show us the imports where that error is being raised, as well as what `import jinja2; print(jinja2)` outputs.